# Load data to Azure SQL DW

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse

I have large amount of data to be loaded for SQL DW. What is the best way to get the data to Azure? Should I use Import/Export or AzCopy? How long would it take for each methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of loading data depends on the amount of data. For very small data sets (<100 GB) you can simply use the bulk copy command line utility (bcp.exe) to export the data from SQL Server and then import to Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

For data sets greater than 100 GB, you can export your data using bcp.exe, move the data to Azure Blob Storage using a tool like [AzCopy](http://aka.ms/azcopy), create an external table (via TSQL code) and then pull the data in via a [Create Table As Select (CTAS)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas/) statement. This works well update to a TB or two depending on your connectivity to the cloud.

For really large data sets, say greater than a couple of TBs, you can use the [Azure Import/Export](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-import-export-service/) service to move the data into Azure Blob Storage and then load the data with PolyBase/CTAS.

Using the PolyBase/CTAS route will allow you to take advantage of multiple compute nodes and the parallel nature of data processing in Azure SQL Data Warehouse - an MPP based system. This will greatly improve the data ingestion performance as each compute node is able to process a block of data in parallel with the other nodes.

One consideration as well is to increase the amount of DWU (compute resources) available in SQL Data Warehouse at the time of the CTAS statement. This will increase the number of compute resources adding additional parallelism which will decrease the total ingestion time.

Answer (score 2):

You can go through the documentation below and figure out which option suits you best.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-overview-load/

If you already have data in an on-premise SQL Server, you can use the migration wizard tool to load that data to Azure SQL DB.

http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/